# Deploy BlackBerry app to BlackBerry 10 Device Simulator from Eclipse BlackBerry plugin

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to build a BlackBerry app, from and Android project using the Eclipse plugin for BlackBerry. I got the BAR file compiled and signed, not I'm trying to figure out how to install it on the BlackBerry 10 Device Simulator. This simulator is run with VMware player. How do I install the BAR file into the virtual simulator?

I tried downloading it with Simulator's browser from my testing website, and clicking the APK or BAR file from the 'downloads' screen brings up an error message "Unable to open the file."

Comment: I've never tried to install to simulator like this, but my first option would be Chrome plugin. Try if it works with that.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will hep You

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/deploy_signed_file_1985504_11.html

Another way is :

blackberry-deploy -installApp -device  <deviceIP> -package  <BAR file path>
 -password  <device password>

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional tool like the BlackBerry Native SDK. This will include the blackberry-deploy tool which you can use to install your app on the simulator.

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/download/